# clion.I can not understand a scanf error that occurred in Clion

Tags: c

It's just my simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[100];
int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
}
```

When I input:

```
0 1 0 2 1 0 1 3 2 1 2 1
```

Then I get:

```
000000000000
```

Then I changed the code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[100];
int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        getchar();       
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
}
```

When I input:

```
0 1 0 2 1 0 1 3 2 1 2 1
```

Then I get:

```
001000201000
```

If I change it to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[100];
int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &a[i]);
        getchar();
        getchar();
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
}
```

When I input:

```
0 1 0 2 1 0 1 3 2 1 2 1
```

Then I get:

```
01021013212
```

The last one output is my want. But I can't understand why it happened after two getchar.

I try to use browser to find why but I failed.

I use the m2 macbookpro,and use the clion for mac,the version is CLion 2023.1.5.

The Toolchains says the Build Tool is "ninja" and the c compiler is the "cc".

Add:gcc-v

```
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I just a newcomer to the program, and starting to use the clion. I don't know why is it different from what I learned from the book and whether I should continue to use clion.

I'd appreciate it if you could answer my questions.

I don't know if the generated assembly code mean that, I follow the Online method to get this:

```
.section   __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .build_version macos, 13, 0    sdk_version 13, 3
    .globl _main                           ; -- Begin function main
    .p2align   2
_main:                                  ; @main
    .cfi_startproc
; %bb.0:
    sub    sp, sp, #48
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 48
    stp    x29, x30, [sp, #32]             ; 16-byte Folded Spill
    add    x29, sp, #32
    .cfi_def_cfa w29, 16
    .cfi_offset w30, -8
    .cfi_offset w29, -16
    stur   wzr, [x29, #-4]
    stur   wzr, [x29, #-8]
    b  LBB0_1
LBB0_1:                                 ; =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    ldur   w8, [x29, #-8]
    subs   w8, w8, #12
    cset   w8, ge
    tbnz   w8, #0, LBB0_4
    b  LBB0_2
LBB0_2:                                 ;   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    ldursw x9, [x29, #-8]
    adrp   x8, _a@PAGE
    add    x8, x8, _a@PAGEOFF
    str    x8, [sp, #16]                   ; 8-byte Folded Spill
    add    x8, x8, x9, lsl #2
    mov    x9, sp
    str    x8, [x9]
    adrp   x0, l_.str@PAGE
    add    x0, x0, l_.str@PAGEOFF
    bl _scanf
    bl _getchar
    bl _getchar
    ldr    x8, [sp, #16]                   ; 8-byte Folded Reload
    ldursw x9, [x29, #-8]
    ldr    w9, [x8, x9, lsl #2]
                                        ; implicit-def: $x8
    mov    x8, x9
    mov    x9, sp
    str    x8, [x9]
    adrp   x0, l_.str.1@PAGE
    add    x0, x0, l_.str.1@PAGEOFF
    bl _printf
    b  LBB0_3
LBB0_3:                                 ;   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    ldur   w8, [x29, #-8]
    add    w8, w8, #1
    stur   w8, [x29, #-8]
    b  LBB0_1
LBB0_4:
    ldur   w0, [x29, #-4]
    ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #32]             ; 16-byte Folded Reload
    add    sp, sp, #48
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
                                        ; -- End function
    .globl _a                              ; @a
.zerofill __DATA,__common,_a,400,2
    .section   __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
l_.str:                                 ; @.str
    .asciz "%d "

l_.str.1:                               ; @.str.1
    .asciz "%d"

.subsections_via_symbols
```

Add:I use the xcode get the same ending.Maybe it's not the clion problem.
Try the fflush;

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[100];
int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &a[i]);
//        getchar();
//        getchar();
        printf("%d", a[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Using the xcode.The output is:

```
0 1 0 2 1 0 1 3 2 1 2 1
000000000000
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[100];
int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12;) {
        if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) == 1) {
            printf("%d", a[i++]);
        } else {
            int ch = getchar();
            if (ch == EOF) break;
            printf("[\\x%x]", ch);
        }
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I try this,and i get:

```
0 1 0 2 1 0 1 3 2 1 2 1
0[\xc2][\xa0]1[\xc2][\xa0]0[\xc2][\xa0]2[\xc2][\xa0]1[\xc2][\xa0]0[\xc2][\xa0]1[\xc2][\xa0]3[\xc2][\xa0]2[\xc2][\xa0]1[\xc2][\xa0]2[\xc2][\xa0]1
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

add:Sometimes it happens and sometimes it doesn't.This repetition happened several times.The most recent one happened just a few minutes ago.What happened on that occasion was as follows.I use the same num from same copy.At the first,it has Normal output in xcode or online coding.But when i use it in the clion,i get a bad output.And if i use the num again in the xcode,the output is bad also,the num in the copy becomes a bad num.If i try to recopy it from this page,the num become normal again.I don't know why it happends but may be a bug.

add:The bug seems sometime happends.

add:I suspect this is because I used a clipboard tool called upaster, as I also ran into this problem in xcode.

add:Now i can ensure it's the clipboard tool's problem.End of this post

Comment: Can't reproduce (MS VC). The first two give the correct output (although in #2 the `getchar()` is unnecessary) and the third one stalls, because the second `getchar()` is stealing input.

Comment: It sounds related to flushing. Depending on command prompt/OS, they may use various different forms of buffering, some will flush when you output a new line character. But you don't use one. Try to add `fflush(stdout);` at the end of each `for` loop - this function call guarantees flushing, portably.

Comment: I've checked and the first code is correct. I don't know why it doesn't work for you. Maybe your compiler or OS is somehow damaged?

Comment: Do you know how to add a flag to the compilation? I would like you to show us the generated assembly code of the first code, usually you can do this by adding flag `-S` (at least on Linux).

Do you know how to use command line? It would be much easier to help you, if you do.

Comment: @Nierusek if the generated assembly code mean this?

Comment: Regarding buffering: When I pointed towards buffering in a comment for a now deleted question, I got this response frmo  
Eric Postpischil: When `stdin` and `stdout` are line buffered (as normal for terminal devices), executing `scanf` flushes `stdout`. C 2018 7.21.3 3 says “Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of characters from the host environment.”

Comment: This isn't related to code generation and disassembly isn't helpful. This is all about the specific console's behavior and the behavior of the standard lib functions. Assuming that code posted is actually what's getting executed... Can't reproduce on gcc neither in Windows nor on Linux.

Comment: ```
#include <stdio.h>
int a[100];
int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ", &a[i]);
//        getchar();
//        getchar();
        printf("%d", a[i]);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```
I try this code and use the xcode.But the output is also.
```
0 1 0 2 1 0 1 3 2 1 2 1
000000000000
Program ended with exit code: 0
``` @Lundin

Comment: Yeah since it isn't possible to reproduce it seems that the only remaining culprits are Clion and Mac, or maybe the standard lib installed by your compiler. Maybe ditch the Mac and use an online compiler instead? https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Check the return value of scanf -- it should always be 1.  If you're getting 0s then you probably have invisible non-printing characters in your input, which are interfering with scanf.

Comment: @Chris Dodd I did what you said

Comment: It looks like you are trying completely random changes in order to see what will stick. May I suggest that this is not a good way to learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12;) {
    if (scanf("%d", &a[i]) == 1) {
        printf("%d", a[i++]);
    } else {
        int ch = getchar();
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        printf("[\\x%x]", ch);
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

this will show you if you're getting extra "invisible" characters in the input that are interfering with scanf

---

From your further post, it is apparent that your input has these `\xc2\xa0` byte pairs in it instead of spaces.  This two-byte sequence is a UTF-8 encoding of a unicode NO-BREAK-SPACE.  You might be able to get scanf to ignore these by using a utf-8 locale (probably just adding `#include <locale.h>` and calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` in the beginning of your program is enough).  Alternately, change your input to use normal spaces rather than these strange spaces.